# PInvoke error marshaling C++ dll into C#, passing struct into method

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

Hi all I am trying to compile a C++ project into a DLL and then use the Structs and methods from C#. I made an openCV program and I need to pass data back and forth. For now I am trying simple things to get familiar with the language since it is the first time I touch C++ and C# ...

So in C++ I have :

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)  
typedef struct 
{
//char *plate;
unsigned int width;
unsigned int height;
//bool hasPlateOn;
//unsigned char *imgData;
} Sframe;
extern "C" Sframe MYCVAPI findPossiblePlates(Sframe& in)
```

And I try to use it from C# like this :

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Sframe
    {
       // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
       // char[] plate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        int width;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        int height;
       // bool hasPlateOn;
      //  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
      //  char[] imgData;
    }

  [DllImport(@"ALPR_pwv.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,EntryPoint = "findPossiblePlates")]
    static extern Sframe findPossiblePlates(Sframe infoOut);
```

But no matter what I try I get errors that the method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.

is there anyone that could help me understand this issue?

Is it even possible to pass and get custom structs among C++ and C# ?

because the end stuct will be much more complex in the end since I have to pass images with data like coordinates etc...

Comment: `UnmanagedType.ByValArray`!? I don't see any arrays in that struct. Try `UnmanagedType.U4` (or `UnmanagedType.U2` depending on architecture).

Comment: Yeah sorry I pasted the wrong attempt. I also tried U1 through U8 but I get the same error all the way

Comment: I edited it to show U4 just for future views... @SaniSinghHuttunen

Comment: Remove `SizeConst = 3`.

Comment: I did I also removed the #pragma pack(push, 2)  from C++and Pack =2 from C# @SaniSinghHuttunen still the same result in any combinations

Comment: `static extern Sframe findPossiblePlates(ref Sframe infoOut);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168919/discussion-between-athinodoros-sgouromallis-and-sani-singh-huttunen).

Answer (score 0):

As @SaniSinghHuttunen mentioned I was missing the ref keyword and had to use MarshalAs.U4 ... Thanks again :)